# Not able to embed css style sheet in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed css style sheet in one of the html but its not working.Can anyone help me out ,your help would be appreciated.
Following is the cide which i have tried.

Css:

```
<head>
<title>Embedded Style Sheets</title>
<style type=”text/css”>
<!--
p { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000000; }
h1 { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
color: #000000; }
-->
</style>
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Embedded Style Sheet </title>
        <link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”
        href=”D:\SelfStudy\HTML\16-Embedded.css” />
    </head> 
        <body>
        <p>This page is using an emebedded style sheet... </p>      
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In css file you don't need tags.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all HTML markup from the CSS file. It should contain only what you now have between `<!--` and `-->` (without those constructs). In the HTML document, fix the `link` tag as follows, assuming that the CSS file is in the same directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="16-Embedded.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.css` file should just be the styles like:

```
p { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000000; }
h1 { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
color: #000000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The css file shouldn't have the html tags or you can add the styles to the head of the html file where it is being used.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to embed an external CSS source file. You know we can embed css in html in three ways and they are:
1. External
2. Internal and
3. Inline

I think here you are trying to embed the first one.

To do so firstly you have to create a file with .css extension and it may be something like you mentioned 16_embeded.css. In this file you have to put just the CSS code not any HTML tags. That means you should put just the following code into your 16_embeded.css file.

```
p { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000000; }
h1 { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
color: #000000; }
```

Now you have to create another file with the extension .html and then put the HTML code portion you mentioned above in this file(.html). Hope it's working well.

Please check the href portion where you are giving the file name is correct or not. Here I should mention that your HTML code portion is correct if the css file path is correct.

Thanks